# How to select text from a text file in ranger preview

Tags: ranger

Yeah, the title says it all :-)
Just to clarify, I would like to open ranger, scroll through some text files while seeing the contents in the right pane and be able to select potions of the current file eg. with my mouse pointer to yank/copy them with alt-c / cmd-c / ...

Comment: Yes, seems like that. Do you have an advice how to use another preview command, that just writes to stdout, which should be selectable by the mouse (depending on your terminal emulator you use).

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to use mouse in preview:

1. select a file for the preview to open
2. type `z` and `m` to select "set mouse_enabled!" macro. This will enable mouse selection on the whole terminal window.
3. do mouse over the preview window to select text. Use `Ctrl` while selecting if need like a visual mode block
4. press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `c` to copy selection to the clipboard buffer
5. disable mouse selection mode by typing `z` and `m` again